# ffmpeg, thumbnail millisecond's precision, missing pictures

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I created a **[sample video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzSGzivdOIHmNEUzRDR1dlRWYzQ)** for thumbnail's exercises in ffmpeg. It's a 1-second video, **25 fps, uncompressed avi**. Each frame is a white number on a black background : "01" for the first frame, "02" for the second one, ... "25" for the last one.

When I tried to extract a **thumbnail with millisecond's precision**, I didn't get exactly what I was expecting. I expected to get 40 pictures of every frames.

In fact, I had 20 pictures with the "01", then 40 pictures with the "02", "03" ... "24", "25", and finally 20 empty pictures from 980 to 999. **It seems that the 20 first leading pictures are missing**.

The following command give me the last picture with "01" :

> ffmpeg.exe -ss 00:00:00.019 -i "Sequence 01.avi" -vframes 1 "Sequence 01_019.png"

The following command give me the first picture with "02" :

> ffmpeg.exe -ss 00:00:00.020 -i "Sequence 01.avi" -vframes 1 "Sequence 01_020.png"

The following command give me the last picture with "25" :

> ffmpeg.exe -ss 00:00:00.979 -i "Sequence 01.avi" -vframes 1 "Sequence 01_979.png"

Then, between 980 and 999, there is nothing.

I already tried moving `-ss` after the `-i` and it doesn't change anything.

Any idea or explanation ?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Interesting. To a first approximation, it seems to be outputting the *nearest* keyframe, rather than always the one before the seek point. But this doesn't happen with a synthetic video I generated using ffmpeg. It then outputs the frame at or after the seek point. Submit to the bug tracker. Usually, this precision isn't required, so the code may not be robust enough.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'll report this on the bug tracker. ... I've done this experiment to discover what is the range for a frame and, then, how to convert time like "hh:mm:ss.frame" to "hh:mm.ss.milliseconds"

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg arguments are order sensitive, so choosing the clip’s start time after the input video causes a change in behavior.

For example, `-ss` before `-i` uses a less accurate seeking ()

```
ffmpeg -ss 30 -i input_vid.mp4 -t 60 -c copy output_clip.mp4
```

On the other hand,  `-ss` after `-i` uses a more accurate seeking

```
ffmpeg -i input_vid.mp4 -ss 30 -t 60 -c copy output_clip.mp4
```

Check [this](http://www.markbuckler.com/post/cutting-ffmpeg/) link for more info.